# How to use Chao1? (BEGINNER)

Tags: r

I am using R for the first time. I am trying to use the Chao1 function to estimate the diversity of my dataset. I have 20 columns, one for each species, and 8 rows (nine if you include the header), one for each plot. Each cell has a number, which is the number of individuals of that species found in that plot. For example, in my Excel file, cell A2 has the value "8", which means that 8 individuals of Species1 were found in the first plot.

I have downloaded the Fossil and Vegan packages, where I believe the Chao1 function is located. They are active in my library. I have imported my dataset as "speciesabund". I am now trying to run Chao1. According to the description (https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/fossil/html/chao1.html) I'm supposed to type

> chao1(x, taxa.row = TRUE)

I assumed "x" was meant to represent my dataset, so I tried

> chao1(speciesabund, taxa.row = TRUE)

instead. It did not work and returned me "Error: Unsupported use of matrix or array for column indexing." I assume this means that I need to do something more to my data before trying to use the Chao function, is that correct? If so, how do I do this?

Thank you so much for your help! I am using this for the **first time**, so I'm sorry if my question is dumb.

Comment: I would use `vegan::estimateR` - something like `estimateR(BCI)` will give chao1 for each plot.

Comment: How do I get Chao1 for the entire sample? Or is that not possible?

Comment: maybe run colSums first - `estimateR(colSums(BCI))`